# Surface tension and Speed of capillary action

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, capillary-action

I have read that the height of meniscus in a capillary is directly proportionate to liquid-air surface tension.

That left me wondering, is the speed at which capillary action occurs also proportionate to surface tension? For example, will a capillary absorb liquids with higher surface tension faster?

Comment: Related - [Rates of Spontaneous Movement of Water in Capillary Tubes](https://harvardforest.fas.harvard.edu/sites/harvardforest.fas.harvard.edu/files/publications/pdfs/Jeje_JColloidal&InterfaceScience_1979.pdf)

Comment: Yes one would expect that. its Just F = ma. It should be related in some way to $S/\rho$ where S is surface tension and $\rho$ is density of the liquid.

Comment: @Prathyush In such a situation, viscous flow resistance is typically much more important than fluid inertia.